# Участь значение даты в MySQL update

Tags: mysql, mysqli, datetime

В таблице MySQL есть поле datetime, в котором хранится дата (поле pay), до которой пользователь оплатил доступ к сайту.
В момент оплаты к значению поля добавляется определенное количество дней, запрос вида

```
UPDATE `table` SET `pay`=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Проблема в том, что на момент обновления поле `pay` может содержать как дату в прошлом, так и в будущем. И если в первом случае логично, что 30 дней добавляем от текущей даты, то во втором - нужно прибавлять дни к значению поля pay.
Возможно ли как то учесть это в запросе? Чтобы предварительно не "дергать" таблицу извлекая из нее значение pay

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `pay`=DATE_ADD(GREATEST(NOW(),`pay`), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: А DATEADD-то тут зачем? просто ```= GREATEST(NOW(),`pay`) + INTERVAL 30 DAY```